# Kerberos how to get principal or client name?

Tags: java, jsp, kerberos

I have a user configured in AD with delegated kerberos ticket:

> klist
>
> Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_527
>
> Default principal: user1@EXAMPLE
>
> Valid starting Expires Service principal 11/27/15 16:28:27 11/28/15 02:28:27 krbtgt/EXAMPLE.com@EXAMPLE.COM

How can I get this 'user1'? On this client domain account (client side jsp? Or server side?) I want to extract this value after button click and pass it back (with backurl) to another java app.

**EDIT:**
My Apache configuration:

```
<Location /kerb >

     AuthType Kerberos

     AuthName "auth-realm"
     KrbMethodNegotiate off
     KrbMethodK5Passwd off
     KrbServiceName HTTP
     Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
     require valid-user
</Location>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /kerb ajp://120.201.131.169:8019/myApp
 ProxyPassReverse /kerb ajp://120.201.131.169:8019/myApp
```

But I received

```
[Sun Dec 13 18:17:32 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1944): [client
 126.185.3.202] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In my case I have an Apache server configured with `mod_kerb` and forwarding http requests to Tomcat by means of AJP.

In such scenario, Tomcat AJP conector is configured with `tomcatAuthentication=false` and I can get user authenticated from JSP and Servlet using `request.getRemoteUser()`.

Obviously, the user string comes with domain info after `@` so you have to consider it.

If you are interested in my solution, I can elaborate my answer.

## Edit

I edit my answer to give more info about configuring Tomcat to use Kerberos.

### Configure NTP

First, it is quite common to have NTP clients configured in every system AD server, Apache server and Tomcat server. If there is no date and time synchronization, it is quite common to get `clock skew too great` or `postdating` problems.

### Create an AD principal for the server

You need to create a principal into AD to use for server principal authentication. It is necessary to get a keytab file for this principal. I am sorry, I can't tell you how to do this.

### Install and configure Kerberos on Apache server

Once you have your server principal and keytab file, it is time to configure Apache server. Install kerberos into that system and configure `/etc/krb5.conf`. A sample of this file is:

```
HERE.YOUR.KERB.DOMAIN = {
    kdc = your.dns.kerb.domain
    admin_server = your.dns.kerb.domain
}
```

Check with:

```
kinit -k -t keytab.file HTTP/principal.dns.name@HERE.YOUR.KERB.DOMAIN
klist
```

that your server is right configured.

### Install and configure mod_auth_kerb

Install `mod_auth_kerb` apache module and configure its use in every `location`, `directory`, `virtual host` or whatever you need, see below. This configuration is very dependent on your kerberos server, you will have to play with some parameters as KDC verification, negotiation, be or not authoritative, ...

The most important parameter is `Krb5Keytab`, but you can check [this page](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/configure.html) to understand all parameters. Here you are with a sample `location`:

```
<Location /sample/>
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "auth-realm"
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    Krb5Keytab /your/path/to/keytab.file
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

When you try to access this location `http://your.apache.server/sample` Apache will try to check user credentials by means of kerberos.

### AJP Configuration

For AJP configuration (I already answer this before, but I cut and paste here and adapt for this question) the procedure is the following:

- Install Apache module for AJP, usually it is called something like `libapache2-mod-jk`. (*In debian/ubuntu you can run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk`*).
- Then you will have a new module called`jk` or similar. You have to enable it (*In debian/ubuntu you can run `sudo a2enmod jk`*).
- Default configuration will serve mostly, open it a see where does `JkWorkersFile` point. This file is needed to configure the `workers` that manage communication with tomcat apps.
- Create workers file (*if it does not exists*). A workers file is more or less as following.

Sample workers file:

```
ps=/
worker.list=worker1,worker2,...

# worker1 definition
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=host or ip
worker.worker1.type=ajp13

# worker2 definition
....
```

Every worker can point to different tomcat server. Port must be the same that configured into `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`. In this file there is a connector for AJP protocol:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" 
    redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false"/>
```

Every worker has to point to this port.

Finally, you can configure your location (or whatever) using `JkMount workerName` to indicate Apache that this url has to be forwarded to the proper worker:

```
<Location /sample/>
    JkMount worker1
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "auth-realm"
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    Krb5Keytab /your/path/to/keytab.file
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

There are plenty of samples an documentation. Here you are with Tomcat official docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

### Web app authentication

You don't need to configure anything about security constraint in `web.xml`, with this configuration, Apache will authenticate users instead Tomcat, and Tomcat will receive user's principal name into HTTP request.

Tomcat (and any other servlet container) will encapsulate the user's principal into `request.getRemoteUser()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds great! I know I have mod_auth_kerb aswell, but I am not familiar with configuration (it is admin side...). Could you elaborate and maybe paste some apache, kerberos, tomcat configuration? I have RHEL with httpd apache configured with Kerberos. On the same host I have tomcat8 with myGui app.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to compile some info and this night I will post it.

Comment: Can I have one more question. Do I need to configure this workers? I have mod_proxy_ajp module. I wondering how to combine mod_auth_kerb with mod_proxy_ajp? Can I create worker files to?

Comment: Which version of apache did you try? I have only 2.2.

Comment: The configuration I showed you has been tested with apache `2.2` and `2.4`, `mod_auth_kerb` and `mod_jk`. I have no experience with `mod_proxy_ajp` but I guess it won't be any problem to use it in a very similar way as I told you.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how does it work. HTTP/principal.dns.name@HERE.YOUR.KERB.DOMAIN - Is it apache or sth else?

Comment: I think you lack basic kerberos concepts, please read doc first. Answering your last question on comment, here you are what does a krb principal means: http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-user/What-is-a-Kerberos-Principal_003f.html

Comment: You have generated keytab for principal.dns but I cannot see reference in mod_auth_kerb configuration - this is  incomprehensible for me.

Comment: Yes it is, see this line `Krb5Keytab /your/path/to/keytab.file`

Comment: Thank you for your patient, I know I am annoying but its only thing I don't undestand. What is principal.dns.name@HERE.YOUR.KERB.DOMAIN. Is it somehow related to your.apache.server/sample or tomcat?

Comment: `HTTP/principal.dns.name@HERE.YOUR.KERB.DOMAIN` is the principal you want to authenticate against Kerberos. Using my Apache sample config it will ask for a valid principal, for example that one. If authenticated, Tomcat will receive the principal through `request.getRemoteUser()`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I don't know what exactly was wrong but now It works.
I can simple get principal from HTTP Header with the following configuration (I moved this configuration from /conf.d to main /conf/httpd.conf file). What is imported. On RHEL httpd server apache user should have rights to read /etc/krb5.keytab. In my case:

> ps -ef | grep httpd
>
> apache   27537 27535  0 16:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd

```
<VirtualHost myhost.domain.com:80>

ServerName myhost.domain.com

<Location /myApp >
#   SSLRequireSSL
AuthType Kerberos     
KrbMethodNegotiate On
KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
KrbServiceName HTTP/nmyhost.domain.com@EXAMPLE.COM
KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb5.keytab
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
Header add X-Remote-User "%{RU}e" env=RU  
</Location>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /myApp ajp://126.101.100.169:8029/myApp
ProxyPassReverse /myApp ajp://126.101.100.169:8029/myApp

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your keytab file. I had similar issue and when i ran

cat httpd.keytab

it showed plain text, which isnt normal, keytab file should contain ASCII chars, its a binary file. Had to regenerate it with Domain Admin account "$user.name" and then it worked.